# Magento checkout/onepage/ is coming blank after login ver 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8

On the website sellerstreets.com when i am checking out after login it is showing a blank page.

I tried some solutions but none is working. Please help me out its quite urgent as the website is live.

Comment: check var/log folder it will say what you made mistakes

Comment: The logs are not coming.. i have also enabled it from admin but still no logs

Comment: which server are you using Apache or Nginx? go to /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/nginx/error.log check here if you got any clue

Comment: I am using shared hosting

Comment: did you recently upgrade Or apply any patch ?

Answer (score 0):

I updated it to 1.9.3.10 and the issue got resolved.
Thanks guys